# Derivative when change variable

Tags: calculus, analysis

This may be a silly question but I am confused with some notation of a derivative function ater changing variable. For example, if I have $f(x) = x^2$. Let $u(x) = 1-e^x$ and $F(x) = f(u(x))$, then if I write
$$
f'(1-e^x) = -e^x\big(2(1-e^x)\big).
$$
Is it correct or not? Or it must be
$$
f'(1-e^x) = 2(1-e^x).
$$
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The former is correct, you must apply chain rule because it is a function composition.

Comment: But you could interpret it as: $f'(x)=2x$ so $f'(1-e^x)=2(1-e^x)$. For the former to be correct I think you must write $(f(1-e^x))'=-e^x(2(1-e^x))$.

Comment: Technically even when you have $f(x) = x^2$, when you take the derivative you will be multiplying by a $1$ because of chain rule.

Comment: Thank you Panphobia, but if I have $F(x) = f(1-e^x)$ and I apply the chain rule, I will have $F'(x) = u'(x)f'(u(x)) = (1-e^x)'f'(1-e^x) = -e^x(2(1-e^x))$. And this is the one that make me confused, do $F'(x)$ and $f'(1-e^x)$ be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Well what you have here is that you are thinking of two different statements. The first time when you have
$$f'(1-e^x)\neq -e^x[2(1-e^x)]$$
what you are really thinking is
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=-e^x[2(1-e^x)]$$
which is true by the chain rule. However, what you have written is $f'$ **evaluated at** $g$ which is in fact just
$$f'(1-e^x)=2(1-e^x)$$
since $f'(x)=2x$ and then you just are plugging in $1-e^x$ for $x$.
So in short $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))$ (or in shorthand $[f(g(x))]'$) and $f'(g(x))$ are two different statements. The first one is the derivative of a composite function, while the second one is just the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $g$.

Comment: Thanks Will Fisher, this is exactly the one that i want to ask. But normally when we write $f'(1-e^x)$. Which one is prefer? The first one or the second one?

Comment: When you write $f'(1-e^x)$, you are saying the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $1-e^x$, which means you first find $f'$ then plug in $1-e^x$ for $x$. This means that your second statement is true, and not this first. This is also not a matter of preference but rather always the case given how you wrote it.